# Riak node join cluster programmatically

Tags: web-services, riak, riak-cs, riak-js

I am trying to make join a Riak node to the cluster programmatic but I can't manage to do that. I have tried this operation through web and Riak_control but I have a 403 forbidden HTTP error code.

I there any other way to join a cluster programmatic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way of doing it. You have to wrap the console commands for building a cluster in a Web service to call them remotely (e.g. RESTful API).

You may also try the experimental [Riak Explorer](https://github.com/basho-labs/riak_explorer), see [Explorer API endpoints, #3](https://github.com/basho-labs/riak_explorer#explorer-api-endpoints).